# Import geth account into metamask

Tags: metamask, private-key

How do I import a keystore file generated in geth into Metamask?

Is there a simple way for me to convert the ciphertext into a private key, can I decrypt it with my passphrase somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **keythereum** https://github.com/ethereumjs/keythereum

You will be able to manage keystore files and decrypt the private key

Comment: is there anyway to do this manually as well, without code?
im just looking for a quick way to convert this keystore file, so i can copy and paste the result into metmask import account.   (will definitely use keythereum later)

Comment: Check this https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3447/how-can-i-get-my-accounts-into-metamask-or-vice-versa